# How to install opendmarc on Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian-wheezy, dmarc, opendmarc

How can I install opendmarc on Debian Wheezy?

I have tried:

```
~ $ echo 'deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports main contrib' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
~ $ apt-get update
~ $ apt-get install opendmarc
```

But it's unable to find the package.

Removed from the repository?
Manual installation?

Answer (score 2):

Best method.  Upgrade off wheezy.  Debian has dropped official support for it.  Which means all the wheeze packages were removed from the primary CDNs. There is no security support for that release.  A wheezy system is almost certain vulnerable.  Running a wheezy mail server seems like a pretty bad idea.

If you really think you still need to run on wheezy, update to use archive mirror.

- http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/

Source

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports main contrib
```